# Msbuild multiple configurations with differing linker settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild, linker

I've got a large project with multiple configurations. I want to add a configuration to my project with different linker settings (link time code generation), but without recompiling all of the individual source files. Is it possible to have a second configuration with identical compiler settings, different linker settings and to only have MSBuild invoke the linker for the second configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Because of tag visual-c++ I assume vcxproj (visual c++ project file)
In theory I think it is possible.
I guess you have to edit vcxproj manually. You’d have to set up exactly *the same IntDir and OutDir in order to work Incremental build and all condition for both configurations for all taks executed before linking* (the same).  Generally I discourage people using the same IntDir and OutDir for different configurations. In company I work fulltime I’d considered this as fatal build bug if I see this way configured release configurations. In case of developer configurations I’d accept it.

Comment: Yeah it is a vcxproj, I should have specified. I appreciate that your solution isn't ideal, but it might do for our case. We have a configuration used for development, and our release configuration is the same, but with link time code generation. I don't mind performing a proper compilation for our actual deployment, it's just to save the time during development. I'll talk it over with my colleagues tomorrow. If you put in as an answer, I'll mark it as correct as although it's not a nice solution per se, it's a perfectly valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, I was able to set the IntDir and OutDir for both configurations to be the same. This worked, although we decided not to do it in the end.